# Submanifold of a Kobayashi hyperbolic manifold

Tags: complex-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, several-complex-variables

Let $M$ be complex manifold which is Kobayashi hyperbolic. Let $N$ be a submanifold of $M$ obtained as the zeroes of an analytic submersion $f : M \rightarrow R$, $R$ complex manifold.

Question : what can be said about the restriction of the Kobayashi metric of $M$ to $N$ ? Is it the Kobayashi metric of $N$ ? Does it change anything if we know $\dim_{\mathbb{C}} N=1$ ?

Comment: All you can say in general is that the metric on the submanifold is larger than the one on the ambient manifold. Examples of stric inequality are plentiful. Just take a generic submersion of the 2-ball to 1-ball.

Comment: right, I see that. well I think you can also say that this metric is smaller than the Kobayashi metric of the submanifold, but that's about it. thanks